# mysql subselect query - find all orders with 'failed' status WOOCOMMERCE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, woocommerce

I'm trying to find all orders with a status of 'failed'

Each query works individually but when I use one as a subquery it fails.

```
 SELECT wp_posts.*
        FROM wp_postmeta
        INNER JOIN wp_posts
        ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
        AND wp_posts.post_type='shop_order'
        AND wp_posts.post_status='publish'
        AND wp_posts.post_date>='{$this->carbon->now()->subDays($days)->toDateTimeString()}'
        AND wp_postmeta.meta_key='_customer_user'
        AND wp_postmeta.meta_value='{$this->user->ID}'
        IN (SELECT DISTINCT wp_postmeta.post_id, tt.taxonomy, te.slug 
        FROM wp_postmeta, wp_terms te, wp_term_relationships tr, wp_term_taxonomy tt
          WHERE wp_postmeta.post_id = tr.object_id
          AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
          AND te.term_id = tt.term_id
          AND tt.taxonomy = 'shop_order_status'
          AND te.slug = 'failed'
        )
```

I'm pretty new to sql, so i think the subquery is wrong.  Does the subquery even make sense?  I'm looking for posts with those conditions and then making another query to find those posts with a te.slug value of 'failed'

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: `AND wp_postMEta.post_ID in (Select distinct wp_postmeta.post_id...)  ` why do you need the other fields?  Though this seems a bit hackish.  There's likely a better way... ah and your mixing join techniques... use `inner` or `,` not both.

Answer (score 0):

In the subquery make sure you select just one column. This will fix your problem. Also, seems you're missing `AND some_column IN ...`. You just have the `IN`

Answer (score 0):

1. Converted , join style to inner join style notation
2. Added a  `AND wp_Postmeta.Post_ID` before in
3. still evaluating if there's a better way to avoid the in..

.

```
SELECT wp_posts.*
FROM wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_posts
  ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
  AND wp_posts.post_type='shop_order'
  AND wp_posts.post_status='publish'
  AND wp_posts.post_date>='{$this->carbon->now()->subDays($days)->toDateTimeString()}'
  AND wp_postmeta.meta_key='_customer_user'
  AND wp_postmeta.meta_value='{$this->user->ID}'
  AND wp_Postmeta.Post_ID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT wp_postmeta.post_id, tt.taxonomy, te.slug 
    FROM wp_postmeta
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships tr
      ON wp_postmeta.post_id = tr.object_id 
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt
      ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN wp_terms te
      ON te.term_id = tt.term_id
    WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'shop_order_status'
      AND te.slug = 'failed')
```

Comment: I think a lot of those join criteria belong in the WHERE and no need for a subquery. Just combine the criteria.

Comment: @MarcusAdams without using a subquery, where would i put tables `tt`, `tr` and `te` in the query?

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you are trying;

```
SELECT ps.*
        FROM wp_postmeta pm, wp_posts ps
        WHERE wp_pm.post_id = ps.ID
        AND ps.post_type='shop_order'
        AND ps.post_status='publish'
        AND ps.post_date>='{$this->carbon->now()->subDays($days)->toDateTimeString()}'
        AND pm.meta_key='_customer_user'
        AND pm.meta_value='{$this->user->ID}'
        AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM wp_terms te, wp_term_relationships tr, wp_term_taxonomy tt
          WHERE pm.post_id = tr.object_id
          AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
          AND te.term_id = tt.term_id
          AND tt.taxonomy = 'shop_order_status'
          AND te.slug = 'failed'
        )
```